# SIP/XMPP: ejabberd and mod_register: REGISTER: forbidden

Tags: xmpp, sip, voip, ejabberd

I am trying to use ejabberd on a local machine, but cannot successfully REGISTER from a client.

I've tried almost every combination of settings on the mod_register module, but still it fails with the FORBIDDEN error.

The current config being tried in ejabberd.yml is:

mod_register:
      ip_access: all
      access: all
      access_from: all

```
REGISTER sip:192.168.1.68;transport=tcp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 192.168.1.85:57353;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj3jvWXSQOzXsmbWdugH8q-ELJns0auMeg;alias
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:f34eda64-7d0f-4e67-8768-8e2937d8812c@ccc-bdp.local>;tag=dIXpNqnkhukX7GVZhgk6lNXNR9MXJD0F
To: <sip:f34eda64-7d0f-4e67-8768-8e2937d8812c@ccc-bdp.local>
Call-ID: kwbzf.F3vjJHLTaOBQ3ShnX94efDkWcJ
CSeq: 34599 REGISTER
Supported: outbound, path
Contact: <sip:f34eda64-7d0f-4e67-8768-8e2937d8812c@192.168.1.85:57352;transport=TCP;ob>;+sip.ice;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000e448c72>"
Expires: 3600
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Content-Length:  0

14:16:51.283 [debug] SIP [tcp/out] ::ffff:172.17.0.4:5060 -> ::ffff:192.168.1.85:57353:
SIP/2.0 403 Forbidden
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 192.168.1.85:57353;branch=z9hG4bKPj3jvWXSQOzXsmbWdugH8q-ELJns0auMeg;alias;received=192.168.1.85;rport=57353
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:f34eda64-7d0f-4e67-8768-8e2937d8812c@ccc-bdp.local>;tag=dIXpNqnkhukX7GVZhgk6lNXNR9MXJD0F
Call-ID: kwbzf.F3vjJHLTaOBQ3ShnX94efDkWcJ
CSeq: 34599 REGISTER
To: <sip:f34eda64-7d0f-4e67-8768-8e2937d8812c@ccc-bdp.local>;tag=2592351295-2481125905
Server: ejabberd 19.02
Content-Length: 0
```

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/919c9d6fb1bea9f19551a7d5d7204a769a621a3e/src/mod_sip.erl

Make sure your hosts-field in ejabberd.yml has included the domain specified in your request-URI of your REGISTER request.